# Failed to sync pure aosp source code from google's server

Tags: android

I'm trying to sync pure Android 7.1.1 source code from google's server following these instructions. http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
I use the latest repo and I can download manifest successfully. But when I do `repo sync -j8`, it fails. errors are showing below

```
Initializing project platform/build/soong ...
 fatal: '../platform/abi/cpp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
 fatal: '../platform/build/soong.git' does not appear to be a git  repository
 fatal: '../platform/bootable/recovery.git' does not appear to be a git repository
 fatal: '../platform/build.git' does not appear to be a git repository
 fatal: '../platform/build/kati.git' does not appear to be a git  repository
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

SSH/git protocol is banned by IT, I'm not sure if it's related to this issue, could anyone give some advice?

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the instructions from the link above (in particular, the `repo init` instructions)?

Comment: I think I did, the only difference is I didn't change global git configurations. But during repo init, it reconfirmed again and I set email as my gmail address